# CocoaPods - hiding the URL of a private git repo

Tags: git, cocoapods

The `Source Location` section of CocoaPods `podspec` file needs a git repo location, e.g.:

```
# ――― Source Location ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― #
#
#  Specify the location from where the source should be retrieved.
#  Supports git, hg, bzr, svn and HTTP.
#
s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/Company/some-private-repo.git" , 
                   :branch => "cocoaPods"}
```

The pod in question contains proprietary binaries, and the git URL which contains the source code is only accessible within the development team.

**Will the git repo URL be publicly visible? Is there a way (and a reason) to hide this URL?**

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide this URL, assuming you're publishing the podspec. From your question I can't see any reason you'd want to publish the spec. You could either 1) leave the podspec at the root of the private repo, and specify the source in your Podfile or 2) create an internal specs repo that's also private.